# PostGIS query with NodeJS, BookshelfJS and Knex

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, postgis, bookshelf.js

I'm on a project with NodeJS, BookshelfJS and ExpressJS.
My database is Postgres with Postgis installed.
My table 'organizations' has a 'lat_lon' geometry column.
I would like to query all the organization within a fixed radius of a specific lat/long point.
I tried something like this:

```
var organizations = await Organization.query(function (qb) {
 qb.where('ST_DWithin(lat_lon, ST_GeomFromText("POINT(45.43 10.99)", 4326), 1000 )') 
}).fetchAll()
```

and more combinations but it doesn't work. 
It returns me an error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: The operator "undefined" is not permitted

It seems it is expecting the operator inside the where condition but I'm already working on the 'lat_lon' column.

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using knex.raw()?

```
var organizations = await Organization.query(function (qb) {
 qb.where(knex.raw('ST_DWithin(lat_lon, ST_GeomFromText("POINT(45.43 10.99)", 4326), 1000 )'))
}).fetchAll()
```

---

**Edit**: use single quotes so that `POINT(45.43 10.99)` is not interpreted as a column name

```
var organizations = await Organization.query(function (qb) {
 qb.where(knex.raw("ST_DWithin(lat_lon, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(45.43 10.99)', 4326), 1000 )"))
}).fetchAll()
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I have this error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): error: select "organizations".* from "organizations" where ST_DWithin(lat_lon, ST_GeomFromText("POINT(45.43 10.99)", 4326), 1000 ) - column "POINT(45.43 10.99)" does not exist". 
My column is called "lat_lon" and is a geometry.

Comment: It works if I do something like this: 'ST_DWithin(lat_lon, ST_MakePoint(45.43,10.99),1000)'. What is the difference?

Comment: As an workaround, whereRaw() can solve the problem where knex.raw() does not work.

Comment: Just saw this and edited to add the info that the double quotes are interpreted in postgres as a column name

Answer (score 0):

I found that [`whereRaw`](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereRaw) was the solution that I was looking for when I encountered a similar situation.

#### Basic Example

If we have the following query using `where`

```
qb.where('id', 2')
```

The `whereRaw` equivalent is

```
qb.whereRaw('id = ?', [2])
```

#### As Applied to Situation from the Question

I believe that this is roughly equivalent to your query

```
qb.whereRaw('ST_DWithin(lat_lon, ST_GeomFromText("POINT(45.43 10.99)", 4326), 1000 )')
```

which could possibly be parameterized as

```
qb.whereRaw(
    'ST_DWithin(lat_lon, ST_GeomFromText("POINT(?, ?)", 4326), ?)',
    [45.43, 10.99, 1000]
)
```

if the Longitude, Latitude, or search radius were to change.